# Easy Digital Downloads (EDD) - Purchase Receipt emails couldn't be logged

Tags: plugins, hooks, email

I'm trying to *log the purchase receipt email* sent out by the EDD plugin, in the database. But I'm unable to do so.

The custom plugin that logs emails is hooked on to `wp_loaded` hook and filters all emails by the following filter.

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail', array( $this, 'log_email' ) );
```

But the purchase receipt emails are not logged.

Note: The custom plugin logs others emails sent. Example, if I use [WP Mail SMTP plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/) to send a test email, the email is perfectly logged into database.

I debugged to see if my hook is invoked at a later point, but I found that EDD sends the purchase receipts emails via `init` hook.

I further debugged and found that my plugin is **not** hooked into global $wp_filter var.

`var_dump( $wp_filter['wp_mail'] );`

Reference:
[WordPress Action hook sequence](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: if it is not hooked, it probably means you hook too late or that you do not understand the execution path. You should probably try to hook earlier (plugins_loaded) at least to check if that is the cause.

Comment: @Mark Kaplun Thanks, I'm trying to do that. I shall leave a reply when I figure out the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_loaded` hook is fired after `init` hook.

So by the time you add your filter, the filter is already called by EDD.

You can either change your hook to `init` and use a high priority or use an earlier hook like `plugins_loaded`.